# Mysql Stored procedure is taking more time than direct query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, indexing

Mysql Stored procedure is taking more time than direct query:

I am using mysql 5.7 AWS RDS. I have executed a query from stored procedure but it is taking 10 seconds and if i execute the same query directly it is taking 3.5 seconds.

The execution plan is same for both queries.

Please help.

(From comment)

```
SELECT  state, state_code, country, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT a.user_id) users,
        fn_score(SUM(sh),SUM(sh)+SUM(sn),SUM(uh),SUM(uh)+SUM(un),
            SUM(bh),SUM(bh)+SUM(bn),SUM(rh),SUM(rh)+SUM(rn),SUM(mad/60),
            IFNULL(SUM(a.tt),0),
            IFNULL(SUM(a.tpd),0),0.10,0,
            IFNULL(SUM(b.os),0),0.15) AS score
    FROM  ut AS a
    INNER JOIN  uts AS b  ON a.user_id = b.user_id
      AND  a.tp_id = b.tp_id
    INNER JOIN  ur u  ON a.user_id= u.id
    GROUP BY  state,state_code,country;
```

Comment: I'm not clear if you running the query and the stored procedure on the same server against the same data and it's not clear if you have run these a few times or just once.AND you could google mysql stored procedure slower than query

Comment: Yes, i am running stored procedure and query on the same server. I have executed the both of the couple of times and they are taking the similar execution time. I have tried the solution with collation which someone suggested but no use.

Comment: Show us the SP; it may trigger some other ideas.

Comment: @Rick James This is the query:                                                              
 SELECT  state,
 state_code,
 country,
 COUNT(DISTINCT a.user_id) users,
 fn_score(SUM(sh),SUM(sh)+SUM(sn),SUM(uh),SUM(uh)+SUM(un),SUM(bh),SUM(bh)+SUM(bn),SUM(rh),SUM(rh)+SUM(rn),SUM(mad/60),IFNULL(SUM(a.tt),0),
 IFNULL(SUM(a.tpd),0),0.10,0,IFNULL(SUM(b.os),0),0.15) AS score
FROM ut AS a
INNER JOIN uts AS b ON a.user_id = b.user_id AND a.tp_id = b.tp_id
INNER JOIN ur u ON a.user_id= u.id
GROUP BY state,state_code,country;

Comment: i have created a stored procedure with the above same query and executing.

Comment: Is there any trigger associated with your tables?

Comment: No one will ask WHY stored procedure was used in the first place? Did you think it'd be faster? There's something else next to execution plan that you need to look at, it's the query profile. Google `mysql profiling` to see how to do it, it'll tell you much more than execution plan does.

Comment: No Triggers associated to the tables.